# d3 function(d,i) - the meaning of i changed as data changed

Tags: d3.js

I have confusion about [this tutorial of D3](http://vogievetsky.github.io/IntroD3/#33). On this page there is some example code:

```
var myData = [
  [15, 20],
  [40, 10],
  [30, 17]
]

var svg = d3.select("div.output svg")

var selA = svg.selectAll("g").data(myData)
selA.enter().append("g")
selA.attr("transform", function(d,i) { // I'm confused!
  return 'translate(70,' + (i*100+50) + ')'
})
selA.exit().remove()

var selB = selA.selectAll('circle')
  .data(function(d) { return d })
selB.enter().append('circle')
selB
  .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return i*80 }) // I'm confused!
  .attr("r", function(d,i) { return d })
selB.exit().remove()
```

My confusion is about the two `function(d,i)` functions. Judging from the code output `i` means different things in the two functions. In the first function, `i` seems to be the index for the `[15,20]`, `[40,10]`, `[30,17]` entries. Therefore the indexes are `0`, `1`, `2`. In the second function `i` seems to be the second dimension index. So the indexes are `0`, `1`, `0`, `1`, `0`, `1`.

I think this has something to do with

```
var selB = selA.selectAll('circle')
  .data(function(d) { return d })
```

but I can't really think through. Could anyone explain to me why `i` meant different indexes in the two functions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first selection you are binding the data ([[],[],[]]) and creating a group for each element in the data, so the function in `selA.attr(..., function(d, i) {})` gets called onces for each element in the outer array (indices 0,1,2).

For the second part, each group in `selA` got bounded to one of the inner arrays, so `selB.enter` gets called 3 times (once for each group), each time with the data that was bounded to the group (each of the inner arrays), so each function in `selB.attr(...)` gets passed each element in each of the inner arrays, hence indices 0,1 three times.

Hope this makes sense :)

Take a look at this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jaimedp/heEyn/

Comment: very insightful! I also found this post to be helpful: [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/)